# How to send form to controller on thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc

I have this codeand it doen't work(i think it's th:action="@{/employee}",because it wants from me, that i put html href)
Sorry for my eng))

If you knows,help me,pleace))))

kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk

```
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "t_user")
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Size(min=2, message = "Не меньше 5 знаков")
    private String username;
    @Size(min=2, message = "Не меньше 5 знаков")
    private String password;
    @Transient
    private String passwordConfirm;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Role> roles;

    public User() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return getRoles();
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPasswordConfirm() {
        return passwordConfirm;
    }

    public void setPasswordConfirm(String passwordConfirm) {
        this.passwordConfirm = passwordConfirm;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

}

    import com.gainground.gainGroung.service.UserService;
import com.gainground.gainGroung.entity.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

import javax.validation.Valid;

@Controller
public class RegistrationController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

 
    @GetMapping("/registration/employee")
    public String registrationEmpl(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("userForm", new User());
        return "employee-registration";
    }
 

        @PostMapping("/registration/employee")
    public String addEmpl(@ModelAttribute("userForm") @Valid User userForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "employee-registration";
        }
        if (!userForm.getPassword().equals(userForm.getPasswordConfirm())){
            model.addAttribute("passwordError", "Пароли не совпадают");
            return "employee-registration";
        }
        if (!userService.saveEmpl(userForm)){
            model.addAttribute("usernameError", "Пользователь с таким именем уже существует");
            return "employee-registration";
        }
       return "redirect:/login";
    }




    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="container mt-5">

    <h1>Регистрация</h1>
    <p>Пожалуйста, заполните эту форму, чтобы создать учетную запись.</p>
    <hr>
        <form action="#" th:action="@{/registration/employee}" th:object="${userForm}" method="post">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Login</h2>
            <p>
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" th:field="*{username}"  class="form-control" placeholder="Username" >
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" th:field="*{password}"  class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        </p>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Зарегестрироваться</button>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

this pom

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.3.2.RELEASE
 

....

<java.version>1.8</java.version>

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.27</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>10</source>
                <target>10</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTPUG.png)

Comment: I am stupid) I forgot add input to passwordConfirm

Answer (score 0):

I am stupid) I forgot add input to passwordConfirm